# cannot convert bool to IO Bool

Tags: haskell

I'm trying to do a function which returns true or false.

`owlFile = ".+\\.owl"`

`testOwlFile src = src =~ owlFile :: Bool`

And i need to use on my do block :

```
main = do
       [src] <- getArgs
       resTestOwlFile <- testOwlFile
       if resTestOwlFile
            then do ontology <- runX(readDocument [withValidate no,withRemoveWS yes ] src >>> getontology)
            else print "error"
```

But i'm having an error which is `Couldn't match excepted type IO BOOL with actual type Bool In the return type of a call of "testOwlFile"`

What can i do for that ?

Comment: Replace `resTestOwlFile <- testOwlFile` with `let resTestOwlFile = testOwlFile :: Bool`

Comment: @user2407038 - It would be better for everyone if you made that an answer. The stats for the Haskell tag look better with answered questions that are excepted.  It also makes it easier to find the answer when searching stackoverflow.  If you think that it is too small to count as a real answer mark it as community wiki so others feel free to edit.

Comment: Your second problem is completely unrelated to the first one, please don't write such follow-up edits. Adding a signature `owlFile :: FilePath` (as you should always do anyway!) should fix that one.

Comment: What you mean by FilePath

Comment: He suggests to add type signatures for `owlFile` and `testOwlFile`.

Comment: You mean `owlFile :: String`?

Comment: Yes, 1) `import Text.Regex.Posix` (or `Text.Regex.PCRE`, or ...), 2) it's `let resTestOwlFile = testOwlFile src` not `let resTestOwlFile = testOwlFile`, 3) add `owlFile :: String` and `testOwlFile :: String -> Bool`, or just write `if src =~ owlFile` in `main` without `let`, 4) note that you can also use `ByteString` instead of `String`.

Comment: It worked with String ! :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Please avoid, generally, to think about "converting". Sometimes you actually need to do that, but normally the type system gives you just the right type at the right spot if you use it correctly.

`IO Bool` is *not* a boolean value, but an action that, possibly together with side effects, will also yield a boolean value. So why would you "convert" a perfectly good pure value to such an action, one that doesn't actually do any of the stuff it's type is there for? That doesn't make much sense. The right thing to do, as already said, is to use the value directly; I'd just put it straight in the `if` condition:

```
main = do
       [src] <- getArgs
       if src =~ owlFile
            then ...
            else ...
```

That said, this conversion `Bool -> IO Bool`, however useless, is certainly possible. Indeed, for any monad<sup>1</sup> `m`, that is one of the fundamental operations:

```
class Monad m where
  return :: a -> m a
```

So you could in principle write

```
       resTestOwlFile <- return testOwlFile
```

But don't. That is always equivalent to `let resTestOwlFile = testOwlFile` (guaranteed by the [monad laws](http://www.haskell.org/haskellwiki/Monad_laws)).

---

<sup>1</sup>
The weaker `Applicative` is actually sufficient.

Comment: hummm i'm having the same problem and i tried the same thing as you mentionned

Comment: Thank you ! So much with your solution ! :)

Answer (score 6):

The problem is that `testOwlFile` is of type `Bool`, but the `<-` notation expects an `IO something`.

If `testOwlFile` did have type `IO Bool`, then `resTestOwlFile` would have type `Bool` and your code would have built fine.

As @user2407038 pointed out in a comment, you can use `let` instead of `<-` when the thing you are defining has the same type as the expression you are defining it with:

```
let resTestOwlFile = testOwlFile
```

Or you could just use `testOwlFile` directly in the `if` statement on the next line.

Note that more generally the `<-` notation expects `m something` for any `m` that's an instance of the `Monad` class, but in this case `m` must be `IO` because you're defining the `main` function and because of other code in the `do` block like `getArgs` and `print`.

Comment: Please use a new question for your new problem

Comment: leftaroundabout solved me the problem ! :) thank you by the way !

Comment: I know he did, but you should still use a new question for new problems :-)

Comment: As i had the problem related to my main problem, i thought it was  useful to put the problem here. Sorry about that :(